# Image is not getting displayed when done dynamic binding inside *ngfor in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular

I have some problem with an `<img>` tag not working as I expect it. Here is my code:

```html
<div  *ngFor="let familyPerson of userDataModel.family" class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 family-member">
   <div class="fm-wrapper">
      <div class="round-frame-bg">
         <div class="round-frame wow animated">
            <img [src] = 'familyPerson.image'>
         </div><!-- /.round-frame -->
      </div><!-- /.round-frame-bg -->

      <p>{{familyPerson.qualities}}</p>
  </div><!-- /.hide -->
</div><!-- /.col-md-4-->
```

`userDataModel.family` is an object containing some properties of family members in json format.

This is working as expected and the value of src is correct but the image is not getting displayed in the browser.

I even checked the network activity and the image is loaded but it's still not getting displayed.

However if I replace the `<img>` tag with one where`src` is harcoded, the image is getting displayed just fine.

What is going wrong and how can I fix that?

Comment: So you are only getting the name of the image from server and not the whole link?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img [src] = "familyPerson.image">
```

the Code above should work on my opinion. You have to use double quotes to get the value from a var.

```
<img src = "{{ familyPerson.image }}">
```

This should also work on my opinion.

Comment: it dint work, whether i used double quotes or single quotes, the data binding is happening in both the cases but the image is not displayed on the broswer.

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:4200/assets/images/{{familyPerson.image}}` This is working because you might have saved the image with the same name in your assets/images directory. You are only getting the name of the image from server and not the whole url. You should get full image url from server like
http://localhost:3000/assets/images/abc.png
or you can get "abc.png" only and change the server path yourself.
You should keep the images to server side so that it should be available when you try to access it

Comment: i used the whole url , its the same problem, the data binding is happening correctly but the image is not shown on the browser.